# On the product over primes $\prod_{p \leq N} \frac{p-1}{p-2}$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, harmonic-numbers

First of all, sorry for my ignorance. I'm just a common guy interested in maths.

I have read a lot about the product
$$\prod^{N} \frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{p}}=\prod^{N} \frac{p}{p-1}$$
(Where $p$ is a prime number); including its behaviour and its relationship with Zeta function and the Harmonic series when $N \to \infty$.

But what's about this other product?
$$\prod^{N} \frac{p-1}{p-2}$$
Is it any lower or upper bound known for it? What is its asymptotic behaviour? Where could I find information about it?

Thank you!

Comment: Note that $\zeta(1)$ doesn't even exist.  ;)

Comment: @Winther  , I have modified my question a bit to show that I'm more interested on the asymptotic behaviour of the function rather than on its divergence. Thank you

Comment: You can find a lower bound (in terms of the first product) by using $\frac{p-1}{p-2} = \frac{1}{1 - \frac{1}{p-1}} > \frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{p}}$. You should avoid $p = 2$ as this leads to a zero in the denominator.

Comment: @Winther Thank you! And is there any way to set an upper bound for it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume that, for this product, you don't want to include $2$ as one of your primes, so I'll consider

$$\prod_{2<p\leq N} \frac{p-1}{p-2}$$

Note that

$$\frac{n}{n-1}$$

is a strictly decreasing function of $n$, so we have that

$$\frac{p_{n-1}}{p_{n-1}-1} \geq \frac{p_n-1}{p_n-2} > \frac{p_n}{p_n-1}$$

where $p_n$ is the $n$th prime ($p_1=2,p_2=3,\cdots$)

So, the product can be bounded by

$$\prod_{n=2}^{\pi(N)} \frac{p_{n-1}}{p_{n-1}-1} \geq \prod_{n=2}^{\pi(N)} \frac{p_n-1}{p_n-2} > \prod_{n=2}^{\pi(N)} \frac{p_n}{p_n-1} $$

Denote $X_k = \prod_{n=1}^{k} p_k$ as the $k$th primorial, and let $\phi(n)$ represent the Euler totient function. We can now bound our product by

$$\frac{X_{\pi(N)-1}}{\phi\left(X_{\pi(N)-1}\right)} \geq \prod_{2<p\leq N} \frac{p_n-1}{p_n-2} > \frac{X_{\pi(N)}}{2\phi\left(X_{\pi(N)}\right)}$$

We can use [Mertens' third theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mertens'_theorems) to give that

$$\frac{X_{\pi(N)}}{\phi\left(X_{\pi(N)}\right)}\sim e^{\gamma} \log N$$

So, the product is asymptotically between $\frac{e^{\gamma}}{2}\log N$ and $e^{\gamma}\log N$, so it is asymptotically logarithmic.

Getting a very precise upper bound is extremely difficult, but we can do it assuming the Riemann Hypothesis using "RH Equivalence 3.25" [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20120731034246/http://aimath.org/pl/rhequivalences).

Comment: Could you help with [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2789800/the-asymptotics-of-the-products-over-primes-prod-limits-2p-le-n-left1-f) on $\prod_{2 < p \le n} \left( 1 - \frac{1}{p-1}\right)$? Seems to be very related (or identical?), but I'm wondering about whether there's a precise constant, and if so what…