# Evaluating the twin prime constant

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analytic-number-theory

How could I evaluate the product
$$\prod_{p>2}\Big(1-\frac1{(p-1)^2}\Big)$$
over the primes, or at least get a good estimate for it? I believe it's around $0.662$.

I thought of writing it as
$$\exp\Big(-\sum_{p> 2}\sum_n \frac{1}{n(p-1)^{2n}}\Big) = \exp\Big(-\sum_n\frac1n\sum_{p>2}\frac1{(p-1)^{2n}}\Big)$$
using the Taylor series for log, but I'm not sure where else to go from here.

Comment: I have seen this at MSE already. So far I found [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2789800/the-asymptotics-of-the-products-over-primes-prod-limits-2p-le-n-left1-f?rq=1), which is without the squaring.

Comment: An excellent [paper](http://www.math.u-bordeaux1.fr/~cohen/hardylw.dvi) "High precision computation of Hardy-Littlewood constants" by Henri Cohen covers the question in detail, and provides the value: $$0.6601618158468695739278121100145557784326233602847\ldots$$

Comment: [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A005597/b005597.txt) has the first $1001$ decimal digits.

Answer (score 1):

Do it with CAS.

I may be misinterpreting what you want, but I bet you can fix it easy. I did this all on an HP prime in a few seconds. You want p to be the ith prime? If so,

$\prod _{p\geq 2}^{m|m\geq p}\left ( 1 - \frac{1}{(ithprime(p)-1)^2}\right )=  M_m$

$M_1=undefined,\ M_2=\frac{3}{4},\ M_3=\frac{45}{65}.....\left (0.6601820....\right)$

Now you can check small values, my hp prime chugged for 3 seconds

@m=500, $\approx$ 0.660182008115, m=750, $\approx$ 0.660173867029.

Hope it helps,