# product $\prod \limits_{i=2}^{\infty} (1+\frac{1}{(p_i -2)p_i})$ for primes $p_i$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I want to calculate the product $\alpha= \prod \limits_{i=2}^{\infty} (1+\frac{1}{(p_i -2)p_i})$ for all primes $p_i >2$.
I calculated this product first with computer and get for the first primes under ten millions $\alpha=1.5147801192603$.
Analytical I tried to expand the product as a telescope sum:
$\alpha=1+\frac{1}{2}(1-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{5}-\frac{1}{7}+\frac{2}{45}+\frac{1}{9}-\frac{1}{11}+\frac{2}{105}+\cdots)$. But this doesn't help me. I don't even know if $\alpha$ converges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that if $\{ a_n \}$ is positive and $a_n \to 0$ then $\prod (1 + a_n)$ and $\sum a_n$ converge/diverge together. Given that $p_n \sim n \log n$ convergence is clear. So at least that.

As for a closed form: this is actually the reciprocal of the [twin primes constant.](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/TwinPrimesConstant.html) This appears in many, many conjectures about the prime numbers.

Comment: thank you, this gives me enough input.

Answer (score 0):

Ideas :

The product can be separated as : $\left(\displaystyle \prod \frac{p-1}{p}\right)\left(\displaystyle \prod \frac{p-1}{p-2}\right)$

But we can't separately take both as $\left(\displaystyle \prod \frac{p-1}{p}\right)=\displaystyle \prod (1-p^{-1})=\frac{1}{\zeta(1)}$ is not defined

The other one is harder and concerns the [First Hardy-Littlewood conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twin_prime#First_Hardy%E2%80%93Littlewood_conjecture), which is, I think, still not proven.

Comment: You have to tread with caution here; both those products are divergent. A bit more care is needed.

Comment: of course @PacoAdajar, I was just trying to bring to light the fact that manipulating Zeta functions' identities could be a good start. I wasn't rigorous here

Comment: See also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2035991/on-the-product-over-primes-prod-p-leq-n-fracp-1p-2) for $\prod \frac{p-1}{p-2}$.